# Count occurrences and each time another repeated line appears 3 times, restart the counting - python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to do the following:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"word":["A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","A","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","B","B"]})
```

**Desired Output:**

[image: desired output]

*Please note* that the counter reset every time another row appears three o more times. If another row only appears one or two time the counter does not reset.

My attempts with numpy, pandas

EX.

```
df['num_aux']=1
df['cumulative_numero']=df.groupby(['word'])['num_aux'].cumsum()
```

Getting same result:

[image: Not desired output]

Comment: Do you mind to explain properly your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to reset the cumcount from the next time only when there are exactly 3 A's (neither when there are 9 A's nor 3 B's)

```
cond1 = df['word'].ne(df['word'].shift())
cond2 = df['word'].groupby(cond1.cumsum()).transform('count').eq(3) & cond1 & df['word'].eq('A')
grouper = cond2.shift(3).cumsum().fillna(0)

df.assign(count=df['word'].groupby([grouper, df['word']]).cumcount().add(1))
```

`df`

```
   word  count
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     A      3
3     A      4
4     A      5
5     A      6
6     A      7
7     A      8
8     A      9
9     B      1
10    A     10
11    B      2
12    B      3
13    A     11
14    A     12
15    A     13
16    B      1
17    B      2
18    B      3
19    A      1
20    B      4
21    B      5
```

im sorry that it is not easy for me to explain this code in English.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class GroupCounter():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.previous_count = 0
        self.previous_key = None
        self.mapper = defaultdict(int)
    
    def __call__(self, current_key):
        self.mapper[current_key] += 1
        if current_key != self.previous_key:
            self.previous_key = current_key
            if self.previous_count >= 3:
                self.mapper[current_key] = 1
                self.previous_count = 1
        else:
            self.previous_count += 1
        return self.mapper[current_key]
```

```
df['count'] = df['word'].apply(GroupCounter())
print(df)
>>>
   word  count
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     A      3
3     A      4
4     A      5
5     A      6
6     A      7
7     A      8
8     A      9
9     B      1
10    A     10
11    B      2
12    B      3
13    A     11
14    A     12
15    A     13
16    B      1
17    B      2
18    B      3
19    A      1
20    B      4
21    B      5
```

1. `previous_count`: Stores the cumulative count of the previous group of elements.
2. `previous_key`: Stores the previously encountered element.
3. `mapper`: A `defaultdict` initialized dictionary that stores the cumulative count of each element.

The `__init__` method initializes the instance attributes `previous_count`, `previous_key`, and `mapper` when a new instance of the class is created.

The class has a method named `__call__` that accepts a parameter called `current_key`. When an instance of the class is used as a function, this method will be executed. The method has the following logic:

1. Increment the count of `current_key` by 1.
2. Check if `current_key` is not equal to `previous_key`:

   a. Update `previous_key` to `current_key`.

   b. If `previous_count` is greater than or equal to 3, reset `mapper[current_key]` to 1 and `previous_count` to 1.

   c. Otherwise, update the value of `previous_count`.
3. If `current_key` is equal to `previous_key`, increment `previous_count` by 1.
4. Finally, return `mapper[current_key]`, which is the cumulative count of the current element.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (which assumes that `df`'s index is the standard index):

```py
df["count"] = df.assign(
    idx=df.index,
    diff_dist=lambda df: df.groupby("word")["idx"].diff().ge(4),
    group=lambda df: df.groupby("word")["diff_dist"].cumsum(),
    count=lambda df: df.groupby(["word", "group"]).cumcount() + 1
)["count"]
```

- Take the index into a column `idx`.
- Then group by `word` and take the `diffs` over the new `idx` column: With that you can identify the "holes", i.e. the places where the so calculated `diffs` are greater or equal to `4`. The new column `diff_dist` has `True` where that's the case, otherwise `False`.
- Now build a new `group` column by again grouping over `word` and then `cumsum`ming over `diff_dist`: That gives a second `groupby` criterion which complements `word` to get the required blocks.
- Use `word` and `group` to group over and take the resp. `cumcount`s (`+ 1` to start at `1`).

Result for the sample:

```
   word  count
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     A      3
3     A      4
4     A      5
5     A      6
6     A      7
7     A      8
8     A      9
9     B      1
10    A     10
11    B      2
12    B      3
13    A     11
14    A     12
15    A     13
16    B      1
17    B      2
18    B      3
19    A      1
20    B      4
21    B      5
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
from itertools import groupby

data, cnt = [], {}
for v, g in groupby(df['word']):
    g, c = sum(1 for _ in g), cnt.get(v, 1)
    data.extend(range(c, c + g))
    cnt[v] = c + g
    if g >= 3:
        cnt = {v: cnt[v]}

df['count'] = data
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   word  count
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     A      3
3     A      4
4     A      5
5     A      6
6     A      7
7     A      8
8     A      9
9     B      1
10    A     10
11    B      2
12    B      3
13    A     11
14    A     12
15    A     13
16    B      1
17    B      2
18    B      3
19    A      1
20    B      4
21    B      5
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. My objection is the same as the last time I commented on one of your answers.